# Combinatorical problem with additional layer of probabilities

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose you have a bag with $R$ red balls, $G$ green balls, and $Y$ yellow balls.
Each red balls has probability $p$ to vanish when you draw it. Each green and yellow ball has probability $q$ to vanish when you draw it. (If a ball vanishes it does not come back into the bag.)

What is the probability that the first non-vanishing ball that you draw out of the bag is green?

Comment: Consider only non-vanishing balls. How many of each color are there ? And then ?

Comment: Thanks, this was also my hypotheses. Answer is then $\frac{G (1-q)}{R(1-p)+ (G+Y) (1-q) }$, right?

Comment: @trueblueanil: Did I get your hint right?

Comment: Yes, you got the hint right.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Glad to be of help !